# bash sqlplus command not found

Tags: sql, macos, oracle, bash

I am trying to install sqlplus on my mac following the tutorial here: https://tomeuwork.wordpress.com/2014/05/12/how-to-install-oracle-sqlplus-and-oracle-client-in-mac-os/comment-page-1/#comment-6

I have downloaded the two packages (basic and sqlplus) and created all the directories as it says, I moved the necessary files inside the directories.
I created and copied the tnsnames.ora file with the contents:

```
MYDB=

 (DESCRIPTION=

(ADDRESS=

  (PROTOCOL=TCP)

  (HOST=*********)

  (PORT=1521)

)

(CONNECT_DATA=

  (SERVER=dedicated)

  (SID=MYDB-SID)

)  )
```

And i created the .bash_profile as it says in the tutorial.

But what im stuck on is making the `sqlplus` run.

typing in sqlplus returns command not found.

in the tutorial it says i should use `$ sqlplus username/password@database`

where do i get the username and database name from?, I haven't created one yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally, I'd be in the habit of issuing the command as "sqlplus username@database" and let sqlplus prompt me for the password. Also, many examples run with the scott/tiger Oracle database, so you can use those credentials in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your article, you should do the following:

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile 
Add the following line to the end of the file.
alias sqlplus=’rlwrap sqlplus’ 
Now reload the .bash_profile: 
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Looks like you missed these steps.

You can try to execute:

```
$rlwrap sqlplus
```

According to the comments below you do not have sqlplus in the $PATH.
The value of $PATH looks wrong to me: duplicates, quotes.

### Option 1

Execute:

```
export PATH=/Applications/‌​or‌​acle/product/instantclient_64/11.2.0.4.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/us‌​r/s‌​bin:/sbin
```

Then execute in the same console:

```
$ sqlplus (or $ rlwrap sqlplus)
```

It will set value only for the current shell. The main idea is to have full path to the sqlplus binary in the $PATH.

### Option 2

Modify `~/.bash_profile`.
To save as a permanent environment variable edit `~/.bash_profile`. There are some details about setting PATH in the source article.

Comment: I completed this additional step and tried `$rlwrap sqlplus` but I get: _-bash: sqlplus: command not found_

Comment: Then problem could be with your $PATH variable. According to the comment below you have some additional quotes. Open a console and execute `export PATH=/Applications/oracle/product/instantclient_64/11.2.0.4.0/bin:/Applications/or‌​acle/product/instantclient_64/11.2.0.4.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/s‌​bin:/sbin` Then execute sqlplus or rlwrap sqlplus in the same console.

Comment: Ok that worked, as in the sqlplus command but it says dyld: library not loaded and sqlplus crashed. Could you have a look at this screenshot please? http://postimg.org/image/hav4gttlj/

Comment: Are you sure you added export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib to the ~/.bash_profile? You can try to set it in the current shell.  What is an output for `ls $ORACLE_HOME/lib` and `echo $ORACLE_HOME`?

Comment: Heres the output i get http://postimg.org/image/dwbuul25r/ i checked and have `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib` in bash_profile

Comment: As you see there are no files in lib directory. Problem could be with this  step `mv *dylib* /Applications/oracle/product/instantclient_64/11.2.0.4.0/lib/`. Try to check if there are files before moving: `ls  instantclient_11_2/dylib*`. Locate instantclient_11_2 at first. Btw, what is the output for `ls $ORACLE_HOME`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71626/discussion-between-user3124052-and-idobr).

Answer (score 3):

Top down troubleshooting approach

Look for binary - use *type*

```
[bbrandt] ~/ $ type sqlplus
sqlplus is aliased to `rlwrap sqlplus'
```

Where is my binary.. hidden behind an alias, let's unalias

```
[bbrandt] ~/ $ unalias sqlplus
[bbrandt] ~/ $ type sqlplus
 sqlplus is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus
```

Found it! What happens if I modify my binary search-path?

```
[bbrandt] ~/ $ echo $PATH
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin:/home/bbrandt/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
[bbrandt] ~/ $ export PATH=/home/bbrandt/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

Now, where is my binary?

```
[bbrandt] ~/ $ type sqlplus
bash: type: sqlplus: not found
[bbrandt] ~/ $
```

This is where you are... look in your $PATH variable

Comment: This is my $PATH variable `~ $ echo $PATH
”/Applications/oracle/product/instantclient_64/11.2.0.4.0″/bin:”/Applications/oracle/product/instantclient_64/11.2.0.4.0″/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` How do I change it? And not sure why I got quotation marks in there ”